# Too large vertical gaps on swing GridLayout

Tags: java, swing

I have written an application that has a JFrame(750, 700) using BorderLayout(). NORTH is a JMenuBar(), SOUTH is a Jbutton(), and CENTER is a JPanel() which uses CardLayout. I replace the CENTER panel with my different data panels based on function. I created my CardLayout panels using GUI Builder. All works fine. My GUI panels all work, but I have no idea how they work behind the scenes. As a result, I decided to build them manually. My first attempt is the Preferences panel. As written, it displays pretty much as I intend. I use GridLayout() and set a Jpanel() for each row and then add my components to each of these panels (probably not the best solution, but at least I understand what is going on). To get this to display the way I want I set gridRows = 15, even though I only have 6 rows of data (1 being blank). I would like to have gridRows = 6, but then my spacing over the display is way off with large vertical gaps between components. I tried using grid.setVgap(1), but with no affect. I would like to understand what I am doing wrong before pursuing a better alternative. The code below simulates my Preferences panel:

```
public class LayoutManager {
    
    private JPanel preferences;
    
    LayoutManager() {
        
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Grid Layout");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(750, 700);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

            int gridRows = 15;                                                      // No rows on preferences
            this.preferences = new JPanel();
            GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(gridRows, 1);                          // Only need 6 rows, but spaces better
            grid.setVgap(1);                                                        // 5 between rows
            this.preferences.setLayout(grid);

            int rowStart = 50;                                                      // Left margin
            
            // Look and feel
            JLabel lblLookAndFeel = new JLabel("Look and Feel");
            JComboBox<Object> comboBoxPreferencesLookAndFeel = 
                    new JComboBox<>();
            JPanel lookAndFeelPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(
                    FlowLayout.LEADING));
            lookAndFeelPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(rowStart));              // Left margin
            lookAndFeelPanel.add(lblLookAndFeel);
            lookAndFeelPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));                    // Space between label and combo
            lookAndFeelPanel.add(comboBoxPreferencesLookAndFeel);

            // Theme
            JLabel lblPreferencesTheme = new JLabel("Theme");
            JComboBox<Object> comboBoxPreferencesTheme = new JComboBox<>();
            JPanel themePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
            themePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(rowStart));                    // Left margin
            themePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(30));                          // Indent theme
            themePanel.add(lblPreferencesTheme);
            themePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));                          // Space between label and combo
            themePanel.add(comboBoxPreferencesTheme);

            // Player
            JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel("Player");
            JComboBox<Object> comboBoxPreferencesPlayer = new JComboBox<>();
            JPanel playerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
            playerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(rowStart));                   // Left margin
            playerPanel.add(jLabel1);
            playerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(60));                         // Space between label and combo
            playerPanel.add(comboBoxPreferencesPlayer);

            // Low HI
            JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel("Low HI:");
            JTextField textPreferencesLHI = new JTextField("99.9");
            playerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(20));                         // Space between combo and Low HI label
            playerPanel.add(jLabel2);
            playerPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));                          // Space between label index
            playerPanel.add(textPreferencesLHI);
            
            // Old HC
            JCheckBox chkBoxPreferencesWHC = new JCheckBox("Old HC");
            JPanel oldHCPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
            oldHCPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(rowStart));                     // Left margin
            oldHCPanel.add(chkBoxPreferencesWHC);

            // Debug
            JButton btnPreferencesDebug = new JButton("Debug");
            JPanel debugPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));
            debugPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(rowStart));                     // Left margin
            debugPanel.add(btnPreferencesDebug);
            
            // Spacing at top
            JPanel blankPanel = new JPanel();
            JLabel blankLabel = new JLabel("");
            blankPanel.add(blankLabel);           
            this.preferences.add(blankPanel);
            
            this.preferences.add(lookAndFeelPanel);
            this.preferences.add(themePanel);
            this.preferences.add(playerPanel);
            this.preferences.add(oldHCPanel);
            this.preferences.add(debugPanel);
            
            frame.add(this.preferences);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        new LayoutManager();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using BorderLayout(). NORTH is a JMenuBar(),

You should NOT add the menu bar to the content pane.

The frame has a reserved space for the menu bar.

Instead you should use:

```
frame.setJMenuBar( menuBar );
```

> the display is way off with large vertical gaps between components.

All the components added are resize to fill the space available.

If you have one component, it will fill the entire space.

If you have two components they will each have half the space.

If you want the component to appear at their preferred height, then you need to use a "wrapper" panel. This means the panel with the GridLayout will retain its preferred size, but the wrapper panel will expand as the frame size changes.

So the basic code could be:

```
JPanel gridPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 1) ); // single column any number or rows
gridPanel.add(...);

JPanel wrapper = new JPanel();
wrapper.add( gridPanel );

frame.add(wrapper, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Comment: Beautiful! Worked great. BTW, I did have frame.setMenuBar(menuBar); Thanks.